# How to understand sess.as_default() and sess.graph.as_default()?

Tags: tensorflow

I read the [docs of sess.as_default()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#as_default)

> N.B. The default session is a property of the current thread. If you create a new thread, and wish to use the default session in that thread, you must explicitly add a with sess.as_default(): in that thread's function.

My understanding is that if there are two more sessions when a new thread is created, we must set a session to run TensorFlow code in it. So, to do this, a session is chosen and `as_default()` is called.

> N.B. Entering a with sess.as_default(): block does not affect the current default graph. If you are using multiple graphs, and sess.graph is different from the value of tf.get_default_graph, you must explicitly enter a with sess.graph.as_default(): block to make sess.graph the default graph.

In `sess.as_default()` block, to call a specific graph, one must call `sess.graph.as_default()` to run the graph?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [tf.Session](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session) API mentions that a graph is launched in a session. The following code illustrates this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

graph1 = tf.Graph()
graph2 = tf.Graph()

with graph1.as_default() as graph:
  a = tf.constant(0, name='a')
  graph1_init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with graph2.as_default() as graph:
  a = tf.constant(1, name='a')
  graph2_init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess1 = tf.Session(graph=graph1)
sess2 = tf.Session(graph=graph2)
sess1.run(graph1_init_op)
sess2.run(graph2_init_op)

# Both tensor names are a!
print(sess1.run(graph1.get_tensor_by_name('a:0'))) # prints 0
print(sess2.run(graph2.get_tensor_by_name('a:0'))) # prints 1

with sess1.as_default() as sess:
  print(sess.run(sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('a:0'))) # prints 0

with sess2.as_default() as sess:
  print(sess.run(sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('a:0'))) # prints 1

with graph2.as_default() as g:
  with sess1.as_default() as sess:
    print(tf.get_default_graph() == graph2) # prints True
    print(tf.get_default_session() == sess1) # prints True

    # This is the interesting line
    print(sess.run(sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('a:0'))) # prints 0
    print(sess.run(g.get_tensor_by_name('a:0'))) # fails

print(tf.get_default_graph() == graph2) # prints False
print(tf.get_default_session() == sess1) # prints False
```

You don't need to call `sess.graph.as_default()` to run the graph, but you need to get the correct tensors or operations in the graph to run it. The context allows you to get the graph or session using `tf.get_default_graph` or `tf.get_default_session`.

In the interesting line above, the default session is `sess1` and it is implicitly calling `sess1.graph`, which is the graph in `sess1`, which is `graph1`, and hence it prints 0.

In the line following that, it fails because it is trying to run an operation in `graph2` with `sess1`.

Comment: Very clear answer, I forgot to accept your answer. Sorry.

Comment: Usually, we define a model to train and another model to do test/validation(without some layers, like Drop). Do we need to explicitly separate these two kinds of graphs? In many examples, I don't see the usage of two graphs. But after reading you answer, I think it is necessary to define two graph in corresponding to train and test/valid graphs. Do we need to do that?

Comment: @skytree In tensorflow estimator, you will see examples of calling `model_fn` with different mode to get different graph.